# how to keep get MAC Adderss (machine id) in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I want to get machine id of client computer. Client will log in to my application with his/her login ID.

Now I want to keep **track** of which userID(login id) is used with which MAC address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky.  If your clients are connecting directly to the site and not going though any sort of NAT or proxy then you could do a lookup on it [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/2b125a0e-f67d-476f-b8a0-a21c99279d5b/)  is a pretty good article on getting the mac address.

You might consider using cookies to keep track of the users rather than recording the mac address since there are some situations where you won't be able to get an accurate mac address.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to keep track of a user revisits your site, you should be using cookies rather than the MAC address.

Getting the MAC address from a server is not possible unless you either install an agent on the client such as an ActiveX control or other browser plugin, or you are on the same physical network, in which case you can do a call to translate their IP address with their mac address.

Comment: is it possible through javascript?